# SELECT using GROUP BY and display the total with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Having two tables

Department table

```
//Department
D#          DNAME
-------------------
1           SALES
2        ACCOUNTING
3          GAMES
5          SPORTS
```

Project table

```
//Project
P#      D#
-----------
1001     1
1002     3
1003     5
1004     5
```

When output display it should be something like:

```
Department    Total Project
---------------------------
  1               1
  2               0
  3               1
  5               2
```

Currently my statement

```
SELECT D# FROM DEPARTMENT 
   WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROJECT WHERE DEPARTMENT.D# = PROJECT.D#);
```

but what should i display 0 if no any project in that D# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT D.D#,
   COUNT(p.P#)
FROM Department d
LEFT JOIN Project p
ON Project.D#=Department.D
GROUP BY d.D#;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    SELECT D# , CASE WHEN A.COUNT > 0  THEN D# ELSE 0 END AS TOTAL_PROJECT 
    FROM DEPARTMENT JOIN (SELECT D# , COUNT(*) FROM PROJECT GROUP BY PROJECT.D#) A ON
 DEPARTMENT.D# = A.D#;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple left join with group by could achieve such requirement.

```
SELECT 
  DEPARTMENT.D#,
  COUNT(PROJECT.P#) AS TotalProject
FROM DEPARTMENT
LEFT JOIN PROJECT ON DEPARTMENT.D# = PROJECT.D#
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.D#
```

Comment: until now i also can't sure how to use right join left join. can you give me a link to refer it too? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check below query:

```
SELECT 
D# as 'Dept_ID',count(P#) as 'Count'
from 
department d 
left join project p 
on d.D#=p.D# 
group by d.D#;
```

Comment: `as 'Dept_ID'` is invalid SQL (at least for Oracle). Identifiers must be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes. `'Dept_ID'` is string literal, `"Dept_ID"` is a column name

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 'Dept_ID' represents to column name in report and for mysql, user can change accordingly if he/she wants to use in oracle or sql...